# Starting and Stopping Parse-Server and Parse-Server Dashboard

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

I have Parse-Server and Parse-Server Dashboard installed locally on a Mac/OSX along with Mongodb-runner.

Everything works fine except when I shut down Mongodb-runner.  When I shut down mongodb-runner using `mongodb-runner stop`, and then start all processes back up again......  none of the previously saved data is viewable by the Parse-Server Dashboard.

If I try to retrieve the data using a request like so...  the response is "Object not found"

```
    $ curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
  http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore/2ntvSpRGIK
```

If I shut down the Dashboard and Parse and then start them back up again (without shutting down mongoldb-runner), everything is fine and I can view the data.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you shut down the backing database of MongoDB and you are confused why an object can't be found?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. All data is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongodb-runner is meant to be used for E2E tests and flushes the saved data when you stop it.

You should configure mongodb if you want to persist your data or use a cloud provider like mlab.com so it will also work with your deployments.

Comment: I have mongodb installed on another server which does persist the data during a shutdown. So how does one configure mongodb-runner to persist data during a shutdown?

Comment: Ohhhhh!  Now I get it. Thanks for that. I will uninstall mongodb-runner and install mongodb. Really appreciate your answer.

Comment: No problem! Have a good one! And thanks for using parse-server!

Comment: @hypermiler can you mark as answered please for the other users?

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the source and you can actually tell mongodb-runner NOT to purge the DB each run via an environment variable:

`MONGODB_PURGE=false mongodb-runner start`

Im on windows so I like to use `cross_env`:

`...
"prestart": "cross-env MONGODB_PURGE=false mongodb-runner start",
"start": "nodemon -w src/**/*.ts --exec ts-node ./src/main.ts",
"poststart": "mongodb-runner stop",
...`

Comment: worked for me! Unfortunately this option is not documented